# How to bypass the need of specifing a generic parameter type?

Tags: c#, types, extension-methods, generics

I have an extension method like this one :

```
      public static void ImplementsAttribute<TX, TY>(this Expression<Func<TY>> expression) 
     where TX : Coupling.PropertiesMergerAttribute
  {
     var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
     var name = MetaHelper.GetPropertyName(expression);
     var property = memberExpression.Expression.Type.GetProperty(name);
     var attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(true);
     Assert.IsTrue(attributes.Any(a => a is TX));
  }
```

I can actually use my code like this :

```
     Expression<Func<String>> nameProperty = () => new ImprovisedExplosiveXML().Name;
     nameProperty.ImplementsAttribute<Coupling.UnresolvablePropertiesMergerAttribute, String>();
```

but I would like to not need to specify the second generic parameter type :

```
     Expression<Func<String>> nameProperty = () => new ImprovisedExplosiveXML().Name;
     nameProperty.ImplementsAttribute<Coupling.UnresolvablePropertiesMergerAttribute>();
```

Is there a way of doing this in C# 3.5 ?

Comment: based on the code you have given, i could see you need to either pass the TY as a template parameter or as the Argument to ur extension method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# does not support partial generic inference. If the compiler can't determine all the types you have to supply them all yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I realised that I didn't need the type of the parameter at compile-time so I juste replaced the Expression<Func<TY>> by <Expression<Func<object>> and it does work well for my usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public class AttributeTester
{
    public Attribute[] Attributes { get; set; }

    public void ImplementsAttribute<TAttType>()
    {
         Assert.IsTrue(Attributes.Any(x => x is TAttType));
    }
}

public static void ForProperty<TType, TProperty>(this TType obj, Expression<Func<TType, TProperty>> expression)
{
     var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
     var name = MetaHelper.GetPropertyName(expression);
     var property = memberExpression.Expression.Type.GetProperty(name);
     return new AttributeTester { Attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(true) };
}
```

Then, you should be able to just write it like so:

```
new ImproveisedExplosiveXML().ForProperty(x => x.Name).ImplementsAttribute<SomeAttribute>();
```

Comment: ? I do not understand. I need to look if a property is binded with an attribute. On the last line you suggested me, there is no def. for TX, wich is the attribute I want to look for in the property :
`Assert.IsTrue(attributes.Any(a => a is TX));`

Comment: Updated with new method and class

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! it would work but I can't work with .NET 4, and the AttributeInfo seems to be exclusive to .NET 4 ? is there any workaround ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting ahead of myself. I really should check this answer in a compiler =D The `Attributes` property should be the result of the `property.GetCustomAttributes(true)` call; in this case I believe it returns `Attribute[]`.

Comment: It is working now with object[] instead of Attribute[] and with the AttributeTester in return type.
Thanks for your help !